# Numbers following Django's HTTP Response Code

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on an existing Django project which runs rather slowly (I assume it's mostly due to the AJAX calls). However, in order to prioritize optimization, I'd like to know what the numbers behind the HTTP Response codes mean.

```
[03/Dec/2011 22:25:00] "GET /userbase HTTP/1.1" 200 5914 <--This number
[03/Dec/2011 22:25:39] "GET /cohorts?weekly=true HTTP/1.1" 200 27985 <--This too
[03/Dec/2011 22:26:13] "GET /cohorts?weekly=false HTTP/1.1" 200 11416 <--and this one
```

Since the ones that take longer have larger numbers, I assume it's how long it takes to get a response. But how is this measured? In milliseconds? Clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are the size of the response in bytes. The longer ones are probably larger responses that take longer to calculate. Unfortunately, the output doesn't show time elapsed for requests, though I believe there was a feature request with that at one point.

If you're concerned about how long your requests are taking to complete, you might want to look into installing django-extensions and using the RunProfileServer to build a report.

https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions

http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/runprofileserver.html

If you need more comprehensive production logging, check out django-sentry.

https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions

Comment: Oh, is that what it is? Thanks; I was already contemplating about running the program through a profiler, but I guess this means I should definitely check it out. Thanks for the links as well!

Comment: Happy to help. I periodically get confused with those numbers too, and I've been looking at them for a long time!